# Erroneous contact data retrieved from android contactlist - How to correct?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, contacts, contactscontract

I am experiencing some unusual behaviour from my app - I cannot fathom why, but when a user selects a contact from my listview, the contact which is later retrieved from the handset is somehow not the one the user chose...

UPDATED New code, still not working.

```
    public class nominateContactsActivity extends ListActivity {
public String strName;
public String strTelNo;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "locationPrefs";
public static final ArrayList<NameValuePair> contactsArray = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

setContentView(R.layout.nominatecontactsactivitytest);

this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

//String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER};
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '1'";
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, selection, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
String[] columns = new String[] { 
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        };

int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cursor, columns, to);
this.setListAdapter(adapter);

Button finishButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.finishButton);
finishButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) nominateContactsActivity.this.getListAdapter();
        ListView lv = nominateContactsActivity.this.getListView();
        SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
        Cursor contactsCursor = adapter.getCursor();

        /*for (long id : lv.getCheckedItemIds()) {
            String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";
            String[] args = new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) };
            Cursor cursor=managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, args, null);
        }*/


        for (long id : lv.getCheckedItemIds()) {
            long contactId = contactsCursor.getInt(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
            String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";
            String[] args = new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) };
            Cursor cursor=managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, args, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                strName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                strTelNo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));                                                      
            }
        ;}
            try {
                //Name not operationally useful - why bother storing it - keep this in case later implemented.
                //contactsArray.add(new BasicNameValuePair ("name", strName));
                contactsArray.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number", strTelNo));
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        try {
            storeContacts();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    });
}

public void storeContacts() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
    SharedPreferences userPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
    Editor edit = userPrefs.edit();
    //edit.remove("contactsData").commit();
    String formattedString = contactsArray.toString()
            .replace("number=", "") //remove number name
            .replace(" ","")        //remove spaces
            .replace("[", "")       //remove the right bracket
            .replace("]", "");      //remove the left bracket
    edit.putString("contactsData", formattedString);
    edit.commit();
    String name = userPrefs.getString("Name", null);
    String test = userPrefs.getString("contactsData", null);
    Log.d("", formattedString);
    Log.d("test = ", test);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(nominateContactsActivity.this, rootMenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
          String textSMS = "You have been nominated as a contact by " + name +". Check out www.mywebsite.com for info"; 
          String retrievedContacts = userPrefs.getString("contactsData", null);
          String textPhoneNo;
          textPhoneNo = retrievedContacts;
          //textSMS = "My current location is: " + currentLocation;
          String phoneNo = textPhoneNo;
          try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, textSMS, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(nominateContactsActivity.this, rootMenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent1);       
          } 
          catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS failed, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

The above code works fine except from returning the wrong contact. Is this a scrolling problem, where the id of the checkbox is lost? Please help!!

Thank you

UPDATE -STACKTRACE

```
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at com.app.protect3d.nominateContactsActivity$1.onClick(nominateContactsActivity.java:123)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-11 15:29:43.646: E/AndroidRuntime(3976):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you are displaying Contacts, but you are enumerating Phones. You have to find the contact id, then make a query on the phone table with this id.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful - the error is quite obvious now. 

How exactly to I go about resolving this? It took a solid week of hair-tearing to get this far!

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `onClick`, you have the adapter. From it, you can get the cursor of the contacts.

```
Cursor contactsCursor = adapter.getCursor();
```

in your loop, you can get the contact id :

```
contactsCursor.moveToPosition(selectedPosition);
long contactId = contactsCursor.get(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumn._ID));
```

From there, you can search the Phone like this :

```
String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";
String[] args = new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) };
Cursor cursor=managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, args, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // Get content here
}
```

from there you can use the obtained cursor the way you already are.

### edit - simplification (re-edit, id is really contactId)

you can simply loop on this:

```
for (long contactId : lv.getCheckedItemIds()) {
    String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";
    String[] args = new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) };
    Cursor cursor=managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, args, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // Get content here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I have attempted to integrate this code, though no logcat shows an indexoutofbounds error.

I have edited the code above.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace for that exception ?

Comment: also, i though of a simplification. you can directly obtain the contacts ids from the listview : getCheckedItemIds() and loop over these to query the Phone table

Comment: Updated my question. Ill change the contactID part. Thank you again for your help

Comment: we missed one part : you have to call cursor.moveToFirst when you create it before using it. (i've added it to my answer)

Comment: Thank you - Won't be able to try this out til later tonight - Will update then :) Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you - This appears to work perfectly. If I could buy you a beer I would :p

Comment: njzk2 i updated my answer above where I have attempted to integrate your code....I still can't get it working! I thought the problem was resolved, but i must have broken something...

Comment: when you loop over the selected ids, you don't need to use the contactCursor. the contact id is actually the `id` that you get from the listview. It is my mistake, I used id and contactId for the same thing. See my edit

Comment: Thank you very much - sanity restored!